# Android NoClassDefError (the Class uses Google maps)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, noclassdeffounderror

This is my first time using Google maps in android, but when i navigate to the page which will display the map I get the NoClassDefError.

I have explored the reasons for this and i understand regular Java but i can't seem to locate the problem.

Google-play-services-lib is imported as a library on my project so it doesn't fail on finding the Google Maps (well from what i can tell anyway).

The rest of the App works fine, the error only occurs when this page is loaded/navigated to.

The LogCat output:

```
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732): Process: dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02, PID: 1732
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.WalkRecording
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.CreateWalkActivity$1.onClick(CreateWalkActivity.java:39)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-22 19:24:11.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1732):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

console output:

```
[2013-11-23 00:23:13 - WalkingTours] Android Launch!
[2013-11-23 00:23:13 - WalkingTours] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-23 00:23:13 - WalkingTours] Performing dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen activity launch
[2013-11-23 00:23:13 - WalkingTours] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5556' running compatible AVD 'googleAPIDevice'
[2013-11-23 00:23:13 - WalkingTours] Uploading WalkingTours.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-11-23 00:23:13 - WalkingTours] Installing WalkingTours.apk...
[2013-11-23 00:23:25 - WalkingTours] Success!
[2013-11-23 00:23:25 - WalkingTours] Starting activity dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen on device emulator-5556
[2013-11-23 00:23:29 - WalkingTours] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02/.StartScreen }
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
    <!-- putting android.hardware.camera prevents non-camera devices using this app -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.CreateWalkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_walk" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.HelpScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.WalkRecording"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_walk_recording" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.CreateNewPOIActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_new_poi" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBKYpKfU4zn-3IBkskKsLbwRsQ1-IqFldk" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```

The Class with the error xml (WalkRecording.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".WalkRecording" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

WalkRecording.java

```
package dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class WalkRecording extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walk_recording);
        map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.walk_recording, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

The code that swaps to this class:

```
public void addListenerOnButtons(){

        recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createWalkButton);
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WalkRecording.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```

I have also set it so the gen folder is above the source folder in the build order.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution. I had to go to:

Project>Properties>Order and Export remove the supportv4.jar clean and build, then re add.

Not sure why this is a problem but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

> NoClassDefFoundError

indicates, that something wasn't found at runtime, but were present at compiletime. Maybe some library is missing in the class path.